# Create single HTML file from many html content by keeping header, sidebar & footer section common

Tags: html, wordpress

I dont know whether I am missing out a trick in HTML. I have one simple HTML website in hand which have over 100 HTML pages. For each pages header, sidebar & footer section are same but content is different. Can I simply make this site like Wordpress where page is formed of header.php, footer.php, page.php & sidebar.php. I know I will still have to work on page.php kind of files.

This will simplify the file structure of site. Also I want to know whether this solution is good in SEO perspective or not.

Please help guys.

Comment: `include()`ing files is covered by every basic PHP tutorial out there. I suggest you do some research and learn PHP

Answer (score 0):

Like Bojangles said:

Assuming you're using PHP you can simply create the `header.php`, `footer.php` and `sidebar.php` and then `include` those files from your pages:

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<!-- unique page content goes here -->
<?php include 'sidebar.php' ?>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Edit: This is really basic stuff so I'd recommend reading a beginner tutorial on PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use JS to load the constant content in whenever needed. You'd just do a 
        document.write('your HTML content here');
Place that in an external JavaScript file; and then link to it in the head of your HTML for your pages.